# Positioning multiple Windows Appbars

Tags: windows, winapi, appbar

Does anyone have experience with Windows appbars (application desktop toolbars)? I have figured out how to implement them from the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144177%28VS.85%29.aspx), and I've got it working pretty well. But I'm noticing when there are multiple non-auto-hide appbars on adjacent edges, the top and/or bottom edge ones are always positioned first, so that they span the width of the screen, and left/right appbars are always forced to cede space for the top/bottom ones.

I would like to have the option of making a left or right edge appbar span the entire screen height, even when there is an adjacent top or bottom edge appbar, but from what I'm seeing it looks like the developers of Windows just chose not to make that an option. Even if you only request a space along a *partial* edge for a top or bottom appbar, Windows sets aside the corresponding width along the whole edge. Anybody know a work-around?